# Extending a complex-differentiable function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently trying to understand what it is that is being asked exactly here. The question is:

Given the complex-differentiable function $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}$, $0<|z|<2\pi$, show that there exists a complex-differentiable extension of $f$ onto the set $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\; | \; |z|<2\pi\}$.

So, this just means that I have to check the case where $z=0$, maybe take the limit but I have no tools for that I think. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out Riemann's removable singularity theorem in complex analysis. Also, taking the limit shouldn't be difficult. Have you tried L'Hopital's rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that:

$$
\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-kz}
$$

Then rewrite your function as:
$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\frac{-ze^z}{1-e^{-z}}
$$

Another possibility:

$$
e^z = 1+z+z^2/2+z^3/6+...
$$

Hence your function becomes:

$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\frac{z}{z+z^2/2+z^3/6+...}=\frac{1}{1+z/2+z^2/6+...}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to use L'Hopital's Rule. $\lim_{z \to 0}\frac z {e^{z}-1}= \lim_{z \to 0}\frac 1 {e^{z}}=1$ so extend $f$ by defining $f(0)=1$. To prove that the extended function is differentiable at $0$ apply L'Hopital's Rule again. [$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac 1 z(\frac z {e^{z}-1}-1)= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac {z+1-e^{z}} {z(e^{z}-1)}=\lim_{z \to 0}\frac {1-e^{z}} {e^{z}+ze^{z}-1}=-\frac 1 2$ by yet another application of L'Hopital's Rule.